# Which constructor will be called when registering services in ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

If I have two constructors for a class, how does the service container choose which one to use when I'm registering that service in ConfigureServices?

So lets say I have a class called `MyClass` with a corresponding interface `IMyClass`. In the `ConfigureServices()` method I call the following line of code

```
services.AddScoped<IMyClass, MyClass>();
```

How does it choose which constructor to use if I have the following constructors?

```
MyClass(ILogger logger)

MyClass(ILogger logger, IConfguration configuration)
```

Comment: Cant say for sure but I believe it will use the default without parameter (neither of your constructors).

Comment: It'll use the constructor that can satisfy the most dependencies i.e. bottom one in your case.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39094772/2401021 - the behaviour is to use the first matching constructor where the parameters are known

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The constructor matching is performed by a method called [CallSiteFactory:CreateConstructorCallSite](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/199436b51fba6f0bee469c63ee42fa266d70222d/src/libraries/Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection/src/ServiceLookup/CallSiteFactory.cs#L387). Based on its source code, the algorithm is the following:

- Find all public constructors of the target type

  - If there's none, throw an exception
  - If there's only one, use it
- Sort all constructors by their number of arguments (ctors with most arguments first)

  - Select the one with the most number of parameters that can be injected by DI
  - If there are multiple such ctors, throw an exception
- If there are no constructor that can be used, throw an exception

To clarify when there can be an ambiguity, consider these ctors:

```cs
MyClass(ILogger logger)
MyClass(IConfguration configuration)
```

The DI engine can't decide which one to use, because both have valid parameters that can be injected.

In the following case however, there's no ambiguity because the `int` type isn't registered in the DI engine, and thus can't be injected via DI, and thus the first ctor will be chosen:

```cs
MyClass(ILogger logger)
MyClass(int i)
```

---

So to answer your question: in your case, the second constructor will be used.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it out with the following cases;

1. 1 with an interface (registered), 1 with an interface and a primitive parameter (not registered)

   public Application(ITestClass testClass)

   public Application(ITestClass testClass, string message)

**It choses the first one.**

2. 1 with an interface (registered), 1 with two interfaces (registered)

   public Application(ITestClass testClass)

   public Application(ITestClass testClass, ITestClass2 testClass2)

**It choses the second one.**

3. 1 with an interface (registered), 1 with 2 interfaces (registered) and 1 primitive parameter (not registered)

   public Application(ITestClass testClass)

   public Application(ITestClass testClass, ITestClass2 testClass2, string message)

**It choses the first one again.**

When I registered the string type, **it started to choose the second one.**

So the long story short, it will try to find the most comprehensive one with the only known dependencies.