# InvalidOperationException: Multiple constructors accepting all given argument types have been found in type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I suddenly have the following error message after created my fourth controller in ASP.NET Core 2.2:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: Multiple constructors accepting all given argument types have been found in type 'noblesbank.Controllers.AccountController'. There should only be one applicable constructor.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.TryFindMatchingConstructor(Type instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes, ref ConstructorInfo matchingConstructor, ref Nullable<int>[] parameterMap)


InvalidOperationException: Multiple constructors accepting all given argument types have been found in type 'noblesbank.Controllers.AccountController'. There should only be one applicable constructor.
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.TryFindMatchingConstructor(Type instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes, ref ConstructorInfo matchingConstructor, ref Nullable<int>[] parameterMap)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.FindApplicableConstructor(Type instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes, out ConstructorInfo matchingConstructor, out Nullable<int>[] parameterMap)
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateFactory(Type instanceType, Type[] argumentTypes)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.CreateActivator(ControllerActionDescriptor descriptor)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.CreateControllerFactory(ControllerActionDescriptor descriptor)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvokerCache.GetCachedResult(ControllerContext controllerContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvokerProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionInvokerProviderContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionInvokerFactory.CreateInvoker(ActionContext actionContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcRouteHandler+<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<RouteAsync>b__0(HttpContext c)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Can you please provide us with all the constructors of the AccountController please.

Comment: We need to see the actual code for the controller

Answer (score 5):

Make use of `ActivatorUtilitiesConstructorAttribute` on the constructor which you want to be used in DI.

To know more, try these links:

- [ASP.NET Core Dependency Injection with Multiple Constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931716/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-with-multiple-constructors) and
- [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-3.1#service-lifetimes-and-registration-options)