# LOGGING in .NET 5 multiple constructors with dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

***Background***

I am new to C# dotnet and I need to enable logging into my project. Therefore, I followed some online materials including [Microsoft documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#welog) My implementation is slightly different than the example in the document as I have another constructor with dependency injection. Then I found [Stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32931716/asp-net-core-dependency-injection-with-multiple-constructors) that explains how to handle dependency injection with multiple constructors. After that, I implemented the code as below.

in **Program.cs**

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(builder =>
        {
               builder.ClearProviders();
               builder.AddConsole();
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
               webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Then I created a sample controller and implemented the logger as below.

```
private ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
{
      _logger = logger;
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
      _logger.LogInformation("Test");
      return Ok("Home controller");
}
```

It does work only when the

```
builder.ClearProviders();
builder.AddConsole();
```

are commented in the **Program.cs**

Then I implemented a logger in a class that has a constructor already with dependency injection.

```
private ICachingService _cashService;
private readonly ILogger<ExampleHelper> _logger;
        
        
public ExampleHelper(ICachingService cachingService)
{
     _cashService = cachingService;
}

[ActivatorUtilitiesConstructor]
public ExampleHelper(ILogger<ExampleHelper> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _logger.LogInformation("Example Logger");
}
```

Results are breakpoint of the `_logger.LogInformation("Example Logger");` does not hit and throws the following exception.

> Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentNullException' in
> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll

If further information is needed, I can provide them.

***Question 1*:** Why **Homecontroller** logger is not working when clear providers and add console in **program.cs** ?

***Question 2***: How to avoid exception and print the log in the **ExampleHelper** class ?

Comment: Unless you have an extremely specific reason, having those 2 constructors makes no sense. Just do `public ExampleHelper(ICachingService cachingService,ILogger<ExampleHelper> logger)` and it's going to work OK.

Comment: Calling 2 constructors to instantiate an object is not a thing

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks for the support and I can print the log now. The only issue is when I create an object of this class, I have to pass unwanted parameter unless I use an optional parameter for the logger.

Comment: @DimuthLasantha The issue is that you're creating instances of that class. You are using dependency injection, you don't create instances, you request them to be injected in the constructor

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks for the explanation.