# 'InvalidOperationException: Multiple constructors accepting all given argument types err..' error and ActivatorUtilitiesConstructor attribute was used

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, constructor, partial-classes

I have two partial class files for the Client class. Client is registered with DI in .NET 6.
I am getting an error:

> InvalidOperationException: Multiple constructors accepting all given argument types have been found in type 'xxxx.Client'. There should only be one applicable constructor.

The second partial is autogenerated by NSwag.

'Client' is registered like this: `builder.Services.AddHttpClient<IClient, Client>();`

Instantiated like this: `HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IClient>()`

Shouldn't the ActivatorUtilitiesConstructor attribute have taken care of this?

```
 [ActivatorUtilitiesConstructor] 
    public partial class Client : IClient
    {

        public Client(HttpClient httpClient) : this(string.Empty, httpClient) // Call generated ctor
        {
        }
    ...
```

and

```
 public partial class Client : IClient
    {
        public Client(string baseUrl, System.Net.Http.HttpClient httpClient)
        {
          ...
        }
        ...
```

Comment: See the comments https://stackoverflow.com/a/57016321/495455 , does it work if you don't "derive"  ie remove `: this(string.Empty, httpClient)`

Comment: I tried that. It still happens.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] to make it easy to repro? ActivatorUtilitiesConstructor should work. What happens when you instantiate the Client normally or does the error occur on this line `var app = builder.Build(); `

Comment: Shouldn't the attribute be on the constructor instead of the class?

Comment: @Steven. You are correct and that's why a second pair of eyes helps.